# How to create a UUID for a Julia Package?

Tags: julia

I have a local package which I created from a template. The template repo already had a UUID in the `project.toml` file. I now need to generate a new UUID for the package but don't necessarily need to create a whole package from scratch, just the UUID. Do I still need to use `PackageTemplates.jl` and then copy and paste the UUID or is there a function for this? I tried the suggestion here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-give-a-valid-uuid-to-an-existing-package-and-how-to-desactivate-an-environment/19236 but that is out of date now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Julia code for generating packages (Method `Pkg.generate`) at  `generate.jl` reads:

```
uuid = UUIDs.uuid4()
```

So the correct method seems to be:

```
julia> using UUIDs

julia> UUIDs.uuid4()
UUID("268e34f8-cc7d-4112-bf3a-0d45b12e3d15")
```

Reference:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/blob/b963d05a89cfacaa0fe57752de5f3fb439ccfa43/src/generate.jl#L49